# In the field $F_{3^2} = F_3[x]/(2x^2 + x + 1)$, let $\alpha$ be the root and primitive element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

The elements of $F_{3^2}$ can be represented in 2 ways:

1. As polynomials (degree $\leq 1$) in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $F_3$
2. As $0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^{3^2 - 2}$.

And the $2$ ways can be related by using the fact that
$2\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$ in $F_3[\alpha]$.

But that is true only in $F_3[\alpha]$?

For e.g. I know $\alpha^5 = 2\alpha$ in $F_3[\alpha]$. But if I want to find $\alpha + \alpha$ in $F_{3^2}$, that will be $2\alpha$, where $2$ is just an integer, that will not be $\alpha^5$ right?

Comment: Please make the *body* of your post self-contained, including any information in the title.

Comment: Please be specific on what exactly is it that you want to ask.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $2$ is not an integer, but the element $2$ of the finite field ${\mathbb F}_9$ (and, in fact, an element of the subfield ${\mathbb F}_3$ of ${\mathbb F}_9$). So, for instance, in ${\mathbb F}_9$, $2 = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your skepticism about $\alpha^5 = 2\alpha$ is misplaced. You are absolutely correct about that equation.

We can simplify the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F_3$. Since $2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$, the equation $2\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$ in $F_3[\alpha]$ is equivalent to the equation
$$
\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1.
$$
We can treat this as a *power-reducing identity* to inductively express each power of $\alpha$ (your second representation) as an $F_3$-linear combination of $1$ and $\alpha$ (your first representation).

Here's what this looks like:
$$
\alpha^3 = \alpha \, \alpha^2 = \alpha (\alpha + 1) 
= \alpha^2 + \alpha = (\alpha + 1) + \alpha = 2\alpha + 1
$$
and
$$
\alpha^4 = \alpha \, \alpha^3 = \alpha (2\alpha + 1) 
= 2\alpha^2 + \alpha = 2(\alpha + 1) + \alpha = 2
$$
etc. It's interesting to recalculate $\alpha^4$ as $\alpha^2 \, \alpha^2$ instead:
$$
\alpha^2 \, \alpha^2 = (\alpha + 1) (\alpha + 1) = \alpha^2 + 2\alpha + 1 
= (\alpha + 1) + 2\alpha + 1 = 2
$$
Repeating this process produces the dictionary:
\begin{array}{l|r}
\alpha^n & b\alpha + c \\
\hline 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\alpha & \alpha \phantom{{}+1} \\
\alpha^2 & \alpha + 1 \\ 
\alpha^3 & 2\alpha + 1 \\
\alpha^4 & 2 \\
\alpha^5 & 2\alpha \phantom{{}+1} \\
\alpha^6 & 2\alpha + 2 \\
\alpha^7 & \alpha + 2
\end{array}
Of course, $\alpha^8 = 1$, showing that all of the nonzero elements of the field form the cyclic group of order $8 = 3^2 - 1$. [This is true in general](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Finite_field#/Multiplicative_structure).

Comment: This works (+1). But if it was given that $\alpha$ is a primitive element, that is, a root of unity of order eight, then we can, without calculating this table, conclude that $\alpha^4$ is a root of unity of order two. In other words, $\alpha^4=-1=2$. Consequently $\alpha^5=\alpha\cdot\alpha^4=2\alpha$.